# min max coordinate of cells , given cell length in c#

Tags: c#, xna, coordinates, pixel

Please see attached picture to better understand my question

i have a matrix of cells of [JXI] ,
cell is square in shape with length "a"

my question is .. is there a way to use FOR loop to assign MIN,MAX coordinate to each cell
taking origin (0,0) at one corner

Thanks

[image http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/3544/pixelv.png](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/3544/pixelv.png)

i was trying following code but no success

```
int a ; 
a = 1;
for (int J=1; J<=5; J++)
{
  for (int I = 1; I <= 5; I++)
  {
    double Xmin = ((I - 1)*a );
    double Ymin = ((J - 1) * a);
    double Xmax = (I * a );
    double Ymax = (J * a);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Raj: I think you will need to drag your image link out of the quotes, for us to see the image.

Comment: @Oded I am new user , i am not allowed to post direct links

Comment: What exactly you mean by "no success"?

Comment: i am not getting coordinates as shown in picture

Comment: All min max values are generated properly , show what are you doing with them after.

Comment: @Hun1Ahpu  , i m so sorry , may be bcoz of no rest i didnt pay atteention that this code is fine , actully it is part of 3D geometry of mesh of gamma ray detector , well 

Thank You both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok. Just decide what you should do with max and min values.